Solution for linear first order PDE using method of characteristics
For my thesis I'm trying to find a general solution for this PDE:
$$R\left(1-\frac{3}{2}\tau\right)^{-1/3}\frac{\partial t}{\partial \tau}-\left(1-\frac{3}{2}\tau\right)^{-2/3}\frac{\partial t}{\partial R}=f(R,\tau)$$
with $f$ being a general function of the two variables $R$ and $\tau$.
Following the method of characteristics I arrive to the equations:
$$\frac{d\tau}{ds}=R\left(1-\frac{3}{2}\tau\right)^{-1/3}$$
$$\frac{dR}{ds}=-\left(1-\frac{3}{2}\tau\right)^{-2/3}$$
$$\frac{dt}{ds}=f(R,\tau)$$
Combining the first two I arrive to the curve: $\frac{R^2}{2}-(1-\frac{3}{2}\tau)^{2/3}=C$, but I don't know how to continue from there.
Is there a possible general solution for $t(R,\tau)$ depending on $f(R,\tau)$ or do I need a specific function $f$?

It's possible, in principle, to write a general solution for $t(R,\tau)$ depending on $f(R,\tau)$. From the equations
$$
\frac{dR}{ds}=-\left(1-\frac{3}{2}\tau\right)^{-2/3}\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{dt}{ds}=f(R,\tau) \tag{1}
$$
it follows that
$$
\frac{dt}{dR}=-f(R,\tau)\left(1-\frac{3}{2}\tau\right)^{2/3}. \tag{2}
$$
We can use the equation
$$
\frac{R^2}{2}-\left(1-\frac{3}{2}\tau\right)^{2/3}=C \tag{3}
$$
to eliminate $\tau$ from $(2)$, thus transforming it into a separable ODE. Integrating it, we obtain
$$
t=D-\int_{R_0}^Rf(s,\tau(C,s))\left(\frac{s^2}{2}-C\right)ds, \tag{4}
$$
where $D$ is a constant of integration and
$$
\tau(C,s)=\frac{2}{3}\left[1-\left(\frac{s^2}{2}-C\right)^{3/2}\right]. \tag{5}
$$
Combining $(3)$ and $(4)$, we finally obtain
$$
t(R,\tau)=g(C)-F(C,R), \tag{6}
$$
where $g(\cdot)$ is an arbitrary differentiable function, $F(C,R)$ is the integral on the RHS of $(4)$, and $C$ must be replaced with the LHS of $(3)$ after the integration.
